# Hibernate: cloning entity gives "Removing a detached instance" exception on children

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to clone an entity, removing some children, and save the new entity, but I'm getting an *IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance package.Child* and I don't understand why. I think it's because of the orphan removal annotation, which I need for other methods.

Here's my entity model:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {
    private Set<SubEntity> subEntities;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "main", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<SubEntity> getSubEntities() {
        return subEntities;
    }

    //other fields, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class SubEntity {
    private MainEntity main;
    private Set<Child> children;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_ID")
    public getMainEntity() {
        return main;
    }
  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }   

    //other fields, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    private SubEntity parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    public LayoutComposition getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
  
    //other fields, getters and setters
}
```

I need to clone MainEntity with all of its fields and collections, but each of the cloned SubEntity must have no children.
I'm deep cloning the entity and trying to remove the subentity.children.

```
@Autowired
Repository repository; //interface extending JpaRepository<MainEntity, Long>

MainEntity creating = SerializationUtils.clone(existing); //org.apache.commons.lang3
creating.setId(null);
for (SubEntity s : creating.getSubEntities()) {
    s.setId(null);
    s.getChildren().clear();
}
repository.save(creating);
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Try to remove the parent from each child